# Possible to add a reducer that can read from multiple state slices?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-reducers

I am using `createSlice` to create slices of state. Let's call them `sliceA` and `sliceB`. Mostly these slices are decoupled from each other. However I would like to create one reducer in `sliceA` that has (read) access to both `sliceA` and `sliceB`. Is this possible?

I know I can use `extraReducers` to accept actions that were not defined in the slice. But I think I would still be limited (in these extra reducers) to read only `sliceA`, and not `sliceB`.

Any idea how I could create a reducer that can read from both slices?

Comment: Since the reducer is always triggered by an action, keep in mind that you can access the entire state when dispatching them. If a reducer case needs read access to an outside slice, I'd just pass in that extra information in the payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you can't. Each slice reducer is a standalone encapsulated function that can *only* see its own state.

Per [the Redux FAQ entry on "How can I share state across slices?"](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers), your main options are:

- Reorganize the state tree so that all the needed state is in one place
- [Use an additional "top-level reducer" to run more logic](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers)
- Put more of the relevant data into the action